# Permanently Populate ListView With images?

Tags: android, image, listview, caching, android-bitmap

I'm currently developing an app where I have a listview. This listview is populated with text and images fetched from a XML file online. It's populating correctly however, whenever you scroll, anything that wasn't currently on the screen reloads and recalculates the size of the bitmap to go in the listview. This leads to the scrolling being less fluid and annoying. How can I get my activity to populate the listview with the images and load them one time to stay there?

ImageLoader:

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;

int size;
int placeholderpic;

public ImageLoader(Context context, int size, int placeholderpic) {
    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    this.size = size;
    this.placeholderpic = placeholderpic;
}

public void displayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap != null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(placeholderpic);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b != null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
            memoryCache.clear();
        return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = size;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a = (Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){
        bitmap = b; photoToLoad = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap != null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(placeholderpic);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

ListView Adapter:

```
public class LazyNewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<News> listData;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public LazyNewsAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<News> listData) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.listData = listData;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    News newsItem = listData.get(position);

    View view = convertView;
    if(convertView == null)
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_cell, null);

    TextView newsTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
    TextView newsDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsDate);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsImage);

    newsTitle.setText(newsItem.getNewsTitle());
    newsDate.setText(newsItem.getNewsDate());
    String url = newsItem.getNewsImageUrl();

    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity, 600, R.drawable.placeholder);
    imageLoader.displayImage(url, image);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: its a horrible idea to put a listview inside a scrollview as it confuse the system exactly what are you scrolling list or scrollview

Comment: I lied it's just a listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use cache for that kind of things.

See [Universal Image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to load your images in an efficient way.

You must have only one instance of your imageLoader in an activity, dont instantiate it in each getView:

Do that line in your onCreate instead of getView:

```
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity, 600, R.drawable.placeholder);
```

Comment: Edited original question with ImageLoader I am using.

Comment: We don't really care "your" ImageLoader. Everything depends on how you implemented getView on your adapter.

Comment: Adapter is there now.

Comment: I updated my answer, keep only one image instance, you can instantiate it in onCreate. And use it your getview as you did

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow, sorry. I put the instance of the ImageLoader outside the getView and resulted in a crash.

Comment: The adapter doesn't have onCreate. The adapter is used in the onCreate for a separate class activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save online data to Array List variable. Then load it to list view with using notifydatasetChange

Answer (score 0):

Use the listview optimization for the setting image in ListAdapter here's video tutorial that might help you also be sure to use Glide for setting the image as they take a step forward of recycling your Bitmap

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKGoKnhN_Ys&index=91&list=PL1q3ROAofjeOUwh7lPBnGbg__DUodwLN7